# How to keep the window opened even after the command returned or is killed?

Tags: gnu-screen

I open a detached screen and run some commands in new windows:

```sh
screen -dm -S test
screen -S test -X screen -t htop htop
screen -S test -X screen -t top top
screen -S test -X screen -top dmesg dmesg -w

and also try

screen -dm -S test
screen -S test -x -X screen htop
screen -S test -x -X screen top
screen -S test -x -X screen dmesg -w
```

That works well. When I reattach the screen `screen -r test` and I kill the running app with `ctrl+c`, the window is closed at the same time.

When creating new window manually via `ctrl+a+c` and I run top/htop/whatever inside, if I kill the app, the window stays and I can run new command.

Why? How can I have the same behavior? I want to be able to kill and run the command again in the same window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer

You need to let screen know that you want a shell running in the new window with a command running in that shell. The simplest way (that I know) to accomplish this is to create the window separately from running the command in it:

```sh
screen -S session_name -X screen -t tab_name
screen -S session_name -p tab_name -X stuff "command_to_run \r"
```

**Example:**

```sh
screen -S test -X screen -t htop_tab
screen -S test -p htop_tab -X stuff "htop\r"
```

**Notes:**

- The `\r` is there to simulate hitting the return key.
- `stuff` will let you interact with any running process in that window

#### Explanation

The difference between the manual method and the command you are using is:

- When you create a new window manually, you are creating a window with an interactive shell running in it, and then you type a command in the shell to start a program. When you kill that program, it goes back to the shell and you can do whatever you want.
- Your command, on the other hand, is instructing screen to create a new window with the provided command running in it (i.e. don't run a shell), so when you kill it, there is no process running in the window and it closes

##### Relevant excerpts from the screen man page:

In the **Default Key Bindings** section:

> ```
>   C-a c,             (screen)          Create a new window with
>   C-a C-c                              a  shell  and  switch to
>                                        that window.
> ```

In the description of the internal screen command:

> If a command is specified after "screen", this command (with the given arguments) is started in the window; otherwise, a shell is created.

Comment: The cleanest way of doing it was with tmux. `tmux  send-keys -t :3 "the command" C-m`. It's like directly writing in the terminal. I'll try your solution once I have the opportunity.

Comment: Ah, good to know! I use `byobu` as a wrapper and unfortunately chose `screen` over `tmux` when I set it up on my server 9ish years ago (thinking that it would be more prevalent amongst installs so my scripts would be more universally useful). Now I have a bunch of scripts that use screen, but have realized that in a lot of ways tmux might've been easier if I had learned that from the beginning.

Comment: maybe but tmux doesn't solve all the problems though. I had some issues with inherited environment variables among sessions under the same default tmux server. If you don't want them to be inherited from the default server, you need to create a new tmux server `tmux -L newsrv` and run sessions under it. anyway...